# Viewport issue on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have an issue I'm struggling to overcome. I deployed my site, and noticed that the viewport logic is broken for STOCK browser on Android device. Chrome browser on the same Android device works. Also, iphone6 works, but iphone5 doesnt. I'm dynamically determing the viewport values depending on width of screen.

Here is a test version of the site: 
http://spaniard.ca/workVersions/beta/index.html

I can't change the design and layout, and the site needs to be centered in the middle as it is now.

Does anyone know why on on android stock browser it would NOT work, but on chrome on same device would?

anything will help, thanks!

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "doesn't  work"

Comment: The background image is occupying half the screen. But its the same device.. once browser halfs it.. anywhere else, its full width.. check in browser for proper behaviour. Thanks

Comment: looks like Older phones have this issue

Comment: I can't see any problems on android browser. Can you provide screen shot? Which image? What do you mean by halves it?

Comment: http://spaniard.ca/workVersions/beta/work.png

Comment: http://spaniard.ca/workVersions/beta/nowork.png

Comment: that's the same phone.. but i noticed that some older phones display it halved also...

Answer (score 0):

You would have an easier time doing the responsive layout if the hero image was an actual img tag instead of a background image.  You can get the background image to not become cropped by adding the CSS:

```
background-size:contain;
```

On a side note, you need to make sure that the containing elements inside article#what-is-spaniard have percentage widths.

EDIT:
From what I have seen, this isn't an issue of browsers, just lacking the proper code

Answer (score 0):

Providing solution without seeing the code is quite tough. 
Still giving you a suggestion of resolving it.

Just an idea. Try changing the background size in CSS as below :-

background-size: cover;